# App download on mac?

Tags: iphone, ipad

If users download my App on their Mac, would it count as a "download"? Also, does Apple track each download by the device or by the iTunes account?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, downloads from iTunes on a desktop computer will count
2. By account